# PHP in Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, phalanger

I'm deving PHP at the moment using Visual Studio as my IDE.  I've installed the Phalanger Visutal studio integration to get PHP projects etc but I want VS to recognise the PHP start and end tags like the standard ASP ones.

i.e  when I type `<%  %`> into the html editor, I want the PHP tags to behave the same `<? ?>`

I've fiddled in the "Tag Specific Options" and created a tag called ?, but it shows the closing tag wrong, like `<? /?>`

Can it be done?

Cheers

Tim

Comment: Should not "visual studio" be one tag in this case?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Vs.php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php).

Comment: We used this for a while and were big fans of it, it's only downfall at the time (1.5 years ago or so) was that it couldn't handle large projects.  I understand that this has recently been rectified though.

Comment: I don't see why that should stop you. I don't use VS, but I see Vs.php use apache for quick testing, but Id think you can still test it with your own IIS server if you rather want that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.devsense.com/products/php-tools). Phalanger integration now is also built on top of it.

Comment: I've been using Devsense's PHP for a couple of months and it has been a live saver. Breakpoints, debug, variable visualization all within that familiar and fast environment of VS. It's a bit buggy, doesn't visualize SimpleXMLElements real well, at times won't scroll through inline javascript but oh my it's helped me so much. Notepad++, even with debug is a far cry from VS.  Notepad++'s autocomplete is very slow, VS does pretty good. I'm using it for WordPress and it does fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't really think of Visual Studio is a good place to code PHP, but maybe that's just me. I would much rather use DreamWeaver, or even Notepad++ (free) which does syntax highlighting, and more.

Is there a specific reason you want to use Visual Studio for PHP? Usually VS is for Microsoft languages like C#, VB, C++, .NET, etc.

Comment: I get the solution management stuff, I'm familiar with it, we will be using Phalanger someday.  I have created 2 macros for the minute that switch between the asp & php formats.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some specific reason you have to use VS? If not, I'd highly recommend you try Eclipse with PDP, Netbeans, or Aptana. All three are excellent *free* IDE's for PHP that are extensible and offer versions specifically tailored to PHP development.

I do work in .Net and agree VS is an excellent IDE, but the alternatives listed above are equally feature rich and better tailored to coding in PHP.

Comment: I entirely disagree with this recommendation.

(However, I won't vote this down because I see down-votes as punishment for a bad or irresponsible answers. This is an opinion -- which I think can be neither "good" nor "bad" -- and is not irresponsible.)

Answer (score 0):

use VS.php on your VS standard edition or above